# I am using google spreadsheet for scraping product price

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

the url of site from where i am trying to extract price of product is https://www.logsplittersdirect.com/Power-King-PK0342-Log-Splitter/p97062.html

i'm using IMPORTXML() method of google spreadsheet. but it return none i don't no why. thankyou in advance.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.logsplittersdirect.com/Power-King-PK0342-Log-Splitter/p97062.html","//div[@productsPrice]")
```

Comment: Thank you so much  its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website uses dynamic rendering (+ geoblock). Selenium would be required here. But we can try a workaround to get the value in GoogleSheet. Use :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.logsplittersdirect.com/Power-King-PK0342-Log-Splitter/p97062.html";"normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(//script[starts-with(.,'{')],'"",""priceCurrency""'),'""price"":""'))")
```

Output :

[image: Price]